# Query firebase database to compare data

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query my 'rating' table in firebase database. I would like to get all the userRatedEmail's in the table and then compare them to selected email. I am trying this :

```
    var checkRatings = await firebase
                    .Child("rating").Child(auth.CurrentUser.Uid)
                    .OnceAsync<Rating>()

    if (checkRatings.Any((_) => _.Object.userRatedEmail == ratedBabysitter)){ }
```

My firebase database table looks like this :

```
  rating
  6IfKdaH3HbSQ672ZdadadiRW4m62
     -Lc8qNHCmG4Xdsada-9H3
        ratedByEmail:"email00@yahoo.com"
        rating:2
        userRatedEmail:"email77@yahoo.com"
     -Lc8vQUfzNJDdadada
        ratedByEmail:"email01@yahoo.com"
        rating:2
        userRatedEmail:"email88@yahoo.ie"
```

It says expression is not supported and i cant compare the two, userRatedEmail and ratedBabysitter.
Any help with my querying would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: Peter , 
if (checkRatings.Any((_) => _.Object.userRatedEmail == ratedBabysitter)){ }, 
returns - expression not supported.